# Stream camera feed of android to a java based server

Tags: java, android, video-streaming

i am making a simple android app which streams video feed of camera to a custom java based server, i am sending the frames (basically byte[]) using tcp, [i know tcp is not a good approach for video streaming but it is ok for me], android is the client and a java application is the server, i have implemented the client successfully but i am having problem in implementing the java application, the server has to receive the byte[], convert them to image and display in some image container, this is the source code of server:

```
      package dummyserver;

       import java.awt.Image;
       import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
       import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
       import java.io.DataInputStream;
       import java.io.IOException;
       import java.io.InputStream;
       import java.net.ServerSocket;
       import java.net.Socket;
       import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
       import javax.media.jai.PlanarImage;


     /**
         *
       * @author usama
     */
  public class ServerListen implements Runnable{


    CameraFeed camera_feed_ui;
    ServerSocket server_socket=null;
    Socket client_socket=null;
    InputStream in=null;
    int port=9000;
    DataInputStream dis=null;

public ServerListen() {}

public ServerListen(CameraFeed camera_feed_ui)
{
    this.camera_feed_ui = camera_feed_ui;
}



public void run() {

        int len = 0;
        byte[] data;

            while(true)
    {
    try {
        System.out.println("Waiting");
        server_socket = new ServerSocket(port);
        client_socket=server_socket.accept();
        System.out.println("Client arrived");
        System.out.println("Reading Image");
       in=client_socket.getInputStream();

       data=new byte[client_socket.getReceiveBufferSize()];

       in.read(data, 0, client_socket.getReceiveBufferSize());

        Image image = getImageFromByteArray(data);

        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        PlanarImage planar_image=PlanarImage.wrapRenderedImage(bufferedImage);
        System.out.println("Converting byte[] to Image completed");
        camera_feed_ui.displayImage(planar_image);


//        client_socket.close();
        server_socket.close();



        }
 catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("error: "  + ex.toString());
    }

    }
}




public static Image getImageFromByteArray(byte[] byteArray) {
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
    try {
        return ImageIO.read(is);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Unable to converet byte[] into image.");
        return null;

    }


  }
 }
```

Explanation of code:
CameraFeed is the object of my JFrame and it basically contains the image container on which the video is to be displayed (for displaying video i am using [jai](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jai/) [java advance imaging]). The method displayImage(PlanarImage) simply takes the image to be displayed in the container. I think the problem is in converting byte[] to image or i am not correctly extracting byte[] from the sockets, now in the output i am getting a black image.

One more thing, in the client side, i am establishing tcp connection for every frame, it's also clear from this code, i am closing the connection (server_socket.close()) after the frame is received, is this a good approach? How can i make this streaming efficient? if u can please describe the appropriate approach for video streaming from android phone to server (i am asking about algorithm).

Thanks in advance

regards

usama

**Edit:**

*C# code:*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace VideoServer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
   { 

    TcpListener server_socket;
    Socket client_socket;
    Thread video_thread;
    NetworkStream ns;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        server_socket = null;
        client_socket = null;
    }

    private void startVideoConferencing()
    {
        try
        {
            server_socket = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("192.168.15.153"),9000);
            server_socket.Start();
            client_socket = server_socket.AcceptSocket();
            ns = new NetworkStream(client_socket);
            pictureBoxVideo.Image = Image.FromStream(ns);
            server_socket.Stop();

            if (client_socket.Connected == true)
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    startVideoConferencing();
                }
                ns.Flush();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
            video_thread.Abort();
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        video_thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(startVideoConferencing));
        video_thread.Start();
    }

}
}
```

Basically the problem is that what is the equivalent of [Image.FromStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x.aspx) in java, if there is any such method in java which just takes a stream and convert into image while abstracting the low level details of conversion, then this task would also be done for Java. So any idea ??

Comment: Can you post your C# implementation please?

Comment: i have a same problem, do you get any success

Answer (score 1):

Video stream is not just a stream of images (e.g. Jpegs). Depending on codec, its a stream of encoded frames, some of them are only partial (intraframes) frames. So you can not just take a video stream and simply decode it with image codec. You need a video stream codec.

Take a look at this two open source projects to see how they implemented it:

http://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/

http://code.google.com/p/ipcamera-for-android/

Comment: thanks for ur reply, i will look in to these projects, i agree that video stream is not just a stream of images (e.g jpegs) but the approach which i have used should work, cuz i have implemented the server in C# by using the exactly the above approach and it's working fine but i am having problem in implementing in Java.